# Rails application with Ext JS as frontend and need compression of scripts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, compression, extjs

I have a rails application which uses Ext JS for the front end. I have no problem in running the application. But since ext-all.js is bulky, it takes more time to load. I tried to build a custom Ext JS but that did not make much of a difference in size of the Ext JS script.

I was trying to use the Rails cache since I use Rails 2.x. For normal java script files, it has no problem in caching, but for Ext JS scripts, it loads, but I get some DOM object errors such as: `Ext is not defined`. What I am looking for is a compressed version of the Ext JS scripts or some gzip mode. I tried googling and found various options to try compression. But am yet to crack it.

Could anyone provide some pointers on how to solve the compression problem?

Answer (score 0):

Various Ext-specific options for custom builds explained here:

http://extjs.com/learn/Tutorial:Building_Ext_From_Source

For compression there are many options.  YUICompressor is one of the best right now.  Not sure what you mean by "gzip mode." Gzip is an option that should be enabled at the web server level and has nothing to do with Ext or JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Ext is already minified in the production files so to minify further is futile you should only minify your own scripts.

You could look into CacheFly which may provide Ext to your customers faster given it's distributed nature.

The only other option is indeed to do HTTP request level compression using mod_gzip in Apache or the like.

Answer (score 0):

ExtJs size is not much bigger (if any) than most of modern web-sites. It's something below 1MB together with your scripts. And it's loading only one time. I think, with the current network speeds it has nearly of no impact for clients.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a configuration of your web server.
You should use something like this for Apache:

```
FileETag MTime
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 30 days"
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html application/javascript text/javascript text/css
```

It'll make sure that these assets are compressed and unless specified otherwise - cacheable for 30 days.